# how to sum between 3 dynamic field to another dynamic field

Tags: javascript

i have 3 dynamic field where i want to sum 3 dynamic field to another dynamic field, i dont understand how to show the result but i already try pls help

here my dynamic field

```
 cols += '<td><input type="text" style="width: 100px;" id="harga" name="harga[' + counter + ']" placeholder="Harga">  </td>';
 cols += '<td><input type="text" style="width: 50px;" id="qty" name="qty[' + counter + ']" placeholder="Qty" onkeyup="findTotal()">  </td>';
 cols += '<td><input type="text" style="width: 100px;" id="diskon" name="diskon[' + counter + ']" placeholder="Diskon">  </td>';
 cols += '<td><input type="text" id="total" name="total[' + counter + ']" placeholder="Total"></td>';
```

and here my javascript

```
 function findTotal(){
        var sum = 0;
        var qty = document.querySelectorAll("input[name^='qty[']");
        var harga = document.querySelectorAll("input[name^='harga[']");
        var diskon = document.querySelectorAll("input[name^='diskon[']");
        for (var i = 0; i < qty.length; i++)
        {
            sum += parseFloat(
               ((diskon[i].value/100)*harga[i].value)*qty[i].value
            );
            //how to show result must be on total (Dynamic Name)
        }
    }
```

thanks for advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually summing correctly, but not appropriately querying the total input field to assign the value. Your query selector is passing the Element reference, not the id when you call document.getElementById(total[i]).

The quick fix is that you don't need to re-query the total element, as you already have a reference to it in total[i], so you can just do:

```
function findTotal(){
    ...
    for (var i = 0; i < qty.length; i++)
    {
        sum += parseFloat(
           harga[i].value*qty[i].value
        );
        total[i].value = sum;
    }
}
```

You should also consider changing the "id" when you are building the HTML, as these are ideally unique, and you are iterating. You could follow a similar pattern to how you are assigning the "name" attribute, although honestly from what you have written, you could also just leave off the "id" attribute. If you are assigning styles for each element, it would be better to use the "class" attribute.

Comment: ok thanks for your solution -A- but still i dont understand to defined var for set element name for the value and show a result

Comment: In your loop, you have a reference to the total input element, so you can assign to its value property, and the result will show up (as per the code I pasted): 
total[i].value = sum

Comment: like this ? document.querySelectorAll("input[name^='total[']").value = sum; and show nothing

Comment: You need to access the first element of that node list, so document.querySelectorAll("input[name^='total[']")[0].value  (notice the [0] at the end before the .value).  This is presuming you have a single total input field, which isn't clear based on your original cols+= code.